# Website Background Image looking different on IOS devices

Tags: html, css, ios, responsive-design, responsive

Hi i made website using html, css, js, sass (with gulp). I deserve that everything is okay on Notebook version and Android devices but on IOS website has problems. Intro div from the main page has background-image and it's look cool on Android but on IOS devises (Iphone 6, 7, 8+) its very blurred and bad, there is some screenshots and codes.

```
.intro {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    background: url('../img/intro-background-4.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;  }
```

[This is the Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YuBF.jpg)

[This is IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmf3I.jpg)

Can someone solve this problem please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  .intro {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
```

...should fix it.

Comment: @Mert, if you apply it ***after*** your current CSS, it should work. If you want me to look into why it doesn't work in your case, you'll have to provide more than pictures of the result. I need to be able to inspect the CSS rules in DOM, ***while*** it happens and figure out the cause. Consider creating a [mcve] using codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/yiapex-inovasyon-kampi-kkv62?file=/index.html I'm so sorry there is to much code and I specially didn't delete anything. Also you maybe have to know i used gulp with sass. You can check website 'www.yiapex.org' from IOS and Android devices (If you have both) and see the problem by yourself. I added your code after the .intro

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no scrolling inside your `.intro` anyways, so you could simply change `background-attachment` to `scroll` on all devices. That should work. I can't repro your bug (I only have access to emulated iOS devices now and it doesn't happen on any). Besides, you should downsize your background image anyway. I mean... 6k * 3.3k px? Reduce it to max 1.8k wide (I typically use 1.5k). You want your pages to load as fast as possible.